# How to rebuild a struct from bytes after transfer [C#]

Tags: c#

I am using Named Pipes to transfer data from a client (C++) to a server (C#), the client does the following:

```
// C++ Client sending message
struct MESSAGE
   {
   char    cCommand[8];
   string  sParameter;
   };

MESSAGE msg;
strcpy(msg.cCommand, "COMMAND");
strcpy(msg.sParameter, "DO SOMETHING");

DWORD dwWrote = 0;
WriteFile (hpipe, &msg, sizeof(msg), dwWrote, NULL);


// Then, at the receiving end the C# server recieve message:
IntPtr chRequest;
bool fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipeInst, chRequest, uSize, cbRead, OverlappedPtr);
if (fSuccess)
        byte[] temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(chRequest));
```

Now, at the receiving end, I need to transform the temp (byte[]) back into the STRUCT or something equivalent so I can access the members cCommand and sPatameter - but at this point I have no clue how to proceed... In reality doesn't need to be a struct, I just need to extract the data itself.

Note - the STRUCT MESSAGE is something I came up with, meaning that it can be changed if a different format would be helpful in the reconstruction (add the length of sParameter for example?), I just need a COMMAND and PARAMETER to be transfered in a single block (if possible).

Requirements are simple:
- COMMAND is a fixed-length 8-characters long string that indicates what action needs to be performed
- PARAMETER is a variable-length (unless this causes issues) parameter dependant on each COMMAND

For example:
COMMAND = TRANS

PARAMETER = C:\FILE.txt C:\NewFolder\FILE.TXT

(this is just to illustrate, there are a lot more applications)

If possible I would like to extract it as a chunk of data (byte[]) and then pass it along to my application where it could be decomposed, not a fan of reading in the size, then a field, then a size, then a field - that requires that my Communication be overly linked with my implementation.

If there is a more suitable way to implement this transfer please let me know... advice would be welcome...
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the definitions of the struct in c++ you can define it in c# (it may require a little finagling). Then just read the size off of the socket and use [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to marshal it to the c# defined structure.

```
/* Define you structure like this (possibly) */
struct MESSAGE
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanageType.ByValArray, SizeConst=8)]
  byte[]    cCommand;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
  string  sParameter;
};

/* Read data into an instance of MESSAGE like this */
byte[] bytes = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(MESSAGE)];

socket.Receive(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);

try
{
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
    m = (MESSAGE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(MESSAGE));
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Will that work for variable-length strings (sParameter) as well?

Comment: I added another MarshalAs attribute to the MESSAGE struct, but it should work.

Comment: In your professional opinion - is this a good way of doing it? As I mentioned I created the STRUCT as I thought it would be a good choice - but if there are better ways to resolve my problem I am all ears ...

Comment: @Shaitan00: In my opinion using Marshalling is a bit oversized for this task. I'd recommend either a line-based protocol (if you only have simple commands) or a proper serialization mechanism like Protocol Buffers.

Comment: @Shaitan00, There's not enough information on the project to decide whether or not this is a good choice. Does each socket connection only send one command, is there two-way communication, etc. If you are writing both sides right now, then you should probably go with dtb's answer. If you are trying to deal with legacy code, and you have no control over how you communicate, use mine.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for passing data between platforms - don't do the serialization / deserialization yourself. A library like Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) would be a safer bet.

EDIT: If an efficient over-the-wire representation isn't important, it would be even simpler to use JSON (e.g. [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for C# and [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) for C++)

Comment: Since the question is tagged as C#, here are links for .NET implementations: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ and http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/

Comment: doesn't sound like the original c++ app is serializing anything, just sending a byte array on the socket. protocol buffers is a nice tool, but i think it's a little overkill for something like this.

Comment: scottm, to me it looks like it's sending 8 chars + a string instance, which would almost certainly fail if copying the bytes of the struct. I think serialization is important here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx)/[NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) class in the .NET framework that exposes access to named pipes as a Stream which should simplify what you're doing.

A simple solution for passing data would be to use a line-based protocol, e.g. one line = one command with parameters:

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
        new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.In))
{
    pipeClient.Connect();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
    {
        string command;
        while ((command = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received command: {0}", command);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only supported in .NET 3.5 (System.Pipes) I imagine, I am using 2.0 with good-old P/Invoke ... also recall sender in old-school C++

Comment: Then wrap your `hPipeInst` in a `System.IO.Stream` which will give you almost the same benefits (e.g. do all the `OverlappedPtr` stuff for you). And on the sender side just write your line-feed-terminated strings to the pipe, doesn't necessarily have to be structs.

Comment: And use a delimiter between COMMAND and PARAMETER? I need to be able to extract both parts (as I switch on command to figure out what to do with parameter).

Comment: Exactly. For example: `"TRANS C:\\FILE.txt C:\\NewFolder\FILE.TXT\r\n"`